# Mypy throws invalid syntax on method signature

Tags: python, django, mypy

A method called within the below method triggers `mypy` to lint with `test_get_all_boards: test_get_all_boards invalid syntax mypy(error)`. The method in question returns a boolean. I just understand what is wrong with the syntax at `test_get_all_boards:`. Any ideas?

```
@action(detail=False, methods=["post"])
def try_connection(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    result = False
    cache = caches["instance_details"]

    if request.data:
        try:
            details = Jira(**request.data)
            if details:
                if cache[details.uuid]['valid_credentials']:
                    result = True
                else test_get_all_boards(details):
                    cache[details.uuid]['valid_credentials'] = True
                    result = True
        except:
            pass

    return Response({"test_result": result}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: What do you think ``else test_get_all_boards(details):`` means?

Comment: Exactly it doesn't mean much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything between the keyword `else` and the following "`:`". Maybe you mean to use `elif` instead?